# Bounded Type Parameters in java 8 and java more than 10

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends

I wonder what the factor is that below **does not work in java 8 but in java 10**!

`List.of(A.HI, B.HELLO)`

With java 8, my IDE warns me that

> provided type A or B is not the required type

But with java 10, it works!

Is it because of Local Variable Type Inference in Java 10?

I want to **find related docs or posts about this**.
Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /******** does not work in both java 8 and 10 ********/
    Collection<? extends I> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(A.HI);
    list.add(B.HELLO);

    /********* does work in java10  ********/
    Collection<? extends I> list = List.of(A.HI, B.HELLO);
}

interface I {
}
enum A implements I {
    HI
}
enum B implements I {
    HELLO
}
```

Comment: Tried this on Java 13 and it failed with the same error as Java 8. I would wonder why such a problematic "improvement" would be implemented.

Comment: Tried on java 11 as well and it failed there.  Which version of java 10 are you using?  This very much goes against the point of the `? extends` format.

Comment: @ernest_k, BeUndead Sorry for my mistake. I just complement my question.